# How does the dot notation changes the internal representation for an object?

Tags: oop

I am new to Object Oriented Programming. I have come across the concepts of Getters and Setters as well as Dot notation to manipulate the value of an object. It is suggested to use more of Getters and Setters methods instead of Dot notation method.
I tried to understand the reason behind this and found out that using the dot notation might change the internal representation of the object. But, the resource I referred did not tell how exactly this change happens.

Can someone please tell how this change actually looks like?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using getters and setters (or properties in some languages) is common practice because they promote encapsulation, one of the [four principles of object oriented programming](http://crackingjavainterviews.blogspot.com/2013/04/what-are-four-principles-of-oop.html). The idea is that an object should have control over its own properties or members, and that outside classes should not be able to directly manipulate its properties or members.

You asked specifically about the internal representation of an object. Java, for instance, [passes its members by value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/6899860) when you call a get function, but you are accessing the member directly with dot notation. For example take the following class:

```
public class Person {
    public String name = "John";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

In this circumstance you could access the `name` member of the `Person` class through the `getName()` method, or you could access it through dot notation. If you use the `getName()` method then you can't inadvertently change the value of the `name` member. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person person = new Person();
    String name = person.getName();
    name = "Gary";
    Sysetm.out.println(person.getName());
}
```

Will produce the output `John`, whereas the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.name = "Gary";
    Sysetm.out.println(person.getName());
}
```

Will produce the output `Gary`.

The accepted practice for handling this person class is to use encapsulation, and set a private access modifier for its member, like so:

```
public class Person {
    private String name = "John";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Now you can explicitly set the name member to whatever you would like using the `setName` method, but you will never be able to inadvertently change the name member by using dot notation.

Furthermore, there will often be times when you will want to do something with the member before it is returned or before it is set. A simple example would be the following:

```
public class Person {
    private String name = "John";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        // null values are not allowed, and a name must be at least two characters long            
        if (name == null || name.length() < 2) {
            return;
        }
        // name must be capitalzed
        name = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1).toLowerCase();
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

In summation, we do it this way because encapsulation makes code cleaner, more predictable, and more maintainable. I hope this helps!